# What does freq_table[field_pm_value] = map<string, int>(); means?

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, stl, std

I am going through some code and not able to figure out below syntax:

```
freq_table[field_pm_value] = map<string, int>();
```

I am confused what is happening here "map string, int()". freq_table is of type

```
map<string, map<string, int> >& freq_table
```

The full code is https://github.com/vishalsingh8989/Star-Cubing-Algorithm/blob/master/src/csvreader.cpp

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> freq_table[field_pm_value] = map<string, int>();
> ```

This creates a new empty `map` from `string` to `int`, and then copies it to the `freq_table` entry for `field_pm_value`

If `freq_table` has no entry for `field_pm_value`, a new entry is created for it.

Answer (score 1):

> [Map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)
>
> Maps are associative containers that store elements formed by a combination of a key value and a mapped value, following a specific order.

This structure is similar to:
In a house you have different rooms, representing your "outter map container" `map<string, map<string, int> >& freq_table` and in each room you have unique furniture and the amount of them. These furniture are defined in the "inner map".

As `std::map` have unique keys, then you can't have 2 bedrooms in your house and can't have 2 beds in the same room.

In your case you are checking whether you "room" already have furniture in it, otherwise you construct an empty "room".

I am sorry about the awkward analogy, although I hope it may help.